# Editing PresentationML using openxml

Tags: asp.net, openxml, presentationml

Hello everyone i am working on a project in which i have to export some data into a ppt **using openxml** on button click.Here is my code for the aspx page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using ODrawing = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.Extensions1;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System.IO;

namespace TableInPPT
{
    public partial class _Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string templateFile = Server.MapPath("~/Template/Sample.potm");
            string presentationFile = Server.MapPath("~/Template/SmapleNew.pptx");

            PotxToPptx(templateFile, presentationFile);
            //using (PresentationDocument themeDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(templateFile, false))
            using (PresentationDocument prstDoc = PresentationDocument.Open(presentationFile, true))
            {
                AddImage(prstDoc);
                AddTable(prstDoc);

            }
            string itemname = "SmapleNew.pptx";
            Response.Clear();

            Response.ContentType = "pptx";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + itemname + "");
            Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(presentationFile));
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        private  void PotxToPptx(string templateFile, string presentationFile)
        {

            MemoryStream presentationStream = null;

            using (Stream tplStream = File.Open(templateFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                presentationStream = new MemoryStream((int)tplStream.Length);
                tplStream.Copy(presentationStream);
                presentationStream.Position = 0L;
            }

            using (PresentationDocument pptPackage = PresentationDocument.Open(presentationStream, true))
            {
                pptPackage.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.PresentationDocumentType.Presentation);
                PresentationPart presPart = pptPackage.PresentationPart;
                presPart.PresentationPropertiesPart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate",
                   new Uri(templateFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                presPart.Presentation.Save();
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(presentationFile, presentationStream.ToArray());
        }


        private void AddTable(PresentationDocument prstDoc)
        {

            // Add one slide
            Slide slide = prstDoc.PresentationPart.InsertSlide1("Custom Layout", 2);
            Shape tableShape = slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.ChildElements.OfType<Shape>()
                                    .Where(sh => sh.NonVisualShapeProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Title.Value == "TableHolder").SingleOrDefault();
            if (tableShape == null) return;

            // Create Graphic Frame
            OpenXmlCompositeElement gElement = GetGraphicFrame(tableShape);

            // Create a (6x3)Table
            ODrawing.Table openXmlTable = GetSmapleTable();

            // add table to graphic element
            gElement.GetFirstChild<ODrawing.Graphic>().GetFirstChild<ODrawing.GraphicData>().Append(openXmlTable);

            slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Append(gElement);
            slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.RemoveChild<Shape>(tableShape);

            prstDoc.PresentationPart.Presentation.Save();
        }
        private void AddImage(PresentationDocument prstDoc)
        {
            string imgpath = Server.MapPath("~/Template/xxxx.jpg");
            Slide slide = prstDoc.PresentationPart.InsertSlide("Title and Content", 2);
            Shape titleShape = slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.AppendChild(new Shape());
            titleShape.NonVisualShapeProperties = new NonVisualShapeProperties
           (new NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 2, Name = "Title" },
           new NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new ODrawing.ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
           new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new PlaceholderShape() { Type = PlaceholderValues.Title }));
            titleShape.ShapeProperties = new ShapeProperties();

            // Specify the text of the title shape.
            titleShape.TextBody = new TextBody(new ODrawing.BodyProperties(),
                    new ODrawing.ListStyle(),
                    new ODrawing.Paragraph(new ODrawing.Run(new ODrawing.Text() { Text = "Trade Promotion Graph " })));
            Shape shape = slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Elements<Shape>().FirstOrDefault(
                sh => sh.NonVisualShapeProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Name.Value.ToLower().Equals("Content Placeholder 2".ToLower()));
            Picture pic = slide.AddPicture(shape, imgpath);
            slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.RemoveChild<Shape>(shape);
            slide.Save();
            prstDoc.PresentationPart.Presentation.Save();
        }
        private ODrawing.Table GetSmapleTable()
        {

            ODrawing.Table table = new ODrawing.Table();

            ODrawing.TableProperties tableProperties = new ODrawing.TableProperties();
            ODrawing.TableStyleId tableStyleId = new ODrawing.TableStyleId();
            tableStyleId.Text = "{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}";
            //tableStyleId.Text = "{D27102A9-8310-4765-A935-A1911B00CA55}";

            tableProperties.Append(tableStyleId);

            ODrawing.TableGrid tableGrid = new ODrawing.TableGrid();
            ODrawing.GridColumn gridColumn1 = new ODrawing.GridColumn() { Width = 2600000L};
            ODrawing.GridColumn gridColumn2 = new ODrawing.GridColumn() { Width = 2600000L };
            //ODrawing.GridColumn gridColumn3 = new ODrawing.GridColumn() { Width = 1071600L };
            //ODrawing.GridColumn gridColumn4 = new ODrawing.GridColumn() { Width = 1571600L };
            //ODrawing.GridColumn gridColumn5 = new ODrawing.GridColumn() { Width = 771600L };
            //ODrawing.GridColumn gridColumn6 = new ODrawing.GridColumn() { Width = 1071600L };

            tableGrid.Append(gridColumn1);
            tableGrid.Append(gridColumn2);
            //tableGrid.Append(gridColumn3);
            //tableGrid.Append(gridColumn4);
            //tableGrid.Append(gridColumn5);
            //tableGrid.Append(gridColumn6);

            table.Append(tableProperties);
            table.Append(tableGrid);
            for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
            {
                string text1 = "PARAMETERS";
                string text2="VALUES";
                if (row == 2)
                {
                    text1 =Label1.Text ;
                    text2 = TextBox1.Text;
                }
                if (row == 3)
                {
                    text1 = Label2.Text;
                    text2 = TextBox2.Text;
                }
                if (row == 4)
                {
                    text1 = Label3.Text;
                    text2 = TextBox3.Text;
                }
                if (row == 5)
                {
                    text1 = Label4.Text;
                    text2 = TextBox4.Text;
                }
                ODrawing.TableRow tableRow = new ODrawing.TableRow() { Height = 370840L };
                tableRow.Append(new ODrawing.TableCell(
                                    new ODrawing.TextBody(
                                        new ODrawing.BodyProperties(),
                                    new ODrawing.Paragraph(
                                        new ODrawing.Run(
                                            new ODrawing.RunProperties() {Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false , FontSize = 3000},                                         
                                            new ODrawing.Text(text1)))),
                                    new ODrawing.TableCellProperties()));

                tableRow.Append(new ODrawing.TableCell(
                                   new ODrawing.TextBody(
                                       new ODrawing.BodyProperties(),
                                   new ODrawing.Paragraph(
                                       new ODrawing.Run(
                                            new ODrawing.RunProperties() {Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false , FontSize = 3000 }, 
                                           new ODrawing.Text(text2)))),
                                   new ODrawing.TableCellProperties()));

                ODrawing.SolidFill solidFill = new ODrawing.SolidFill();

                ODrawing.SchemeColor schemeColor = new ODrawing.SchemeColor() { Val = ODrawing.SchemeColorValues.Accent6 };
                ODrawing.LuminanceModulation luminanceModulation = new ODrawing.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 75000 };

                schemeColor.Append(luminanceModulation);

                solidFill.Append(schemeColor);

                table.Append(tableRow);
            }
            //for (int row = 1; row <= 3; row++)
            //{
                     //  ODrawing.TableRow tableRow = new ODrawing.TableRow() { Height = 370840L };

            //    for (int column = 1; column <= 6; column++)
            //    {
            //        ODrawing.TableCell tableCell = new ODrawing.TableCell();

            //        TextBody textBody = new TextBody() { BodyProperties = new ODrawing.BodyProperties(), ListStyle = new ODrawing.ListStyle() };

            //        ODrawing.Paragraph paragraph = new ODrawing.Paragraph();

            //        ODrawing.Run run = new ODrawing.Run();
            //        ODrawing.RunProperties runProperties = new ODrawing.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false };
            //        ODrawing.Text text = new ODrawing.Text();
            //        text.Text = "Smaple Text";

            //        run.Append(runProperties);
            //        run.Append(text);
            //        ODrawing.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties = new ODrawing.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false };

            //        paragraph.Append(run);
            //        paragraph.Append(endParagraphRunProperties);

            //        textBody.Append(paragraph);

            //        ODrawing.TableCellProperties tableCellProperties = new ODrawing.TableCellProperties();

            //        ODrawing.SolidFill solidFill = new ODrawing.SolidFill();

            //        ODrawing.SchemeColor schemeColor = new ODrawing.SchemeColor() { Val = ODrawing.SchemeColorValues.Accent6 };
            //        ODrawing.LuminanceModulation luminanceModulation = new ODrawing.LuminanceModulation() { Val = 75000 };

            //        schemeColor.Append(luminanceModulation);

            //        solidFill.Append(schemeColor);

            //        tableCellProperties.Append(solidFill);

            //        tableCell.Append(textBody);
            //        tableCell.Append(tableCellProperties);

            //        tableRow.Append(tableCell);
            //        if (column == 1 && row == 1)
            //        {
                       // tableRow.Append(CreateTextCell("category"));
            //        }
            //    }


           // }

            return table;
        }
        static ODrawing.TableCell CreateTextCell(string text)
        {
            ODrawing.TableCell tc = new ODrawing.TableCell(
                                new ODrawing.TextBody(
                                    new ODrawing.BodyProperties(),
                                new ODrawing.Paragraph(
                                    new ODrawing.Run(
                                        new ODrawing.Text(text)))),
                                new ODrawing.TableCellProperties());

            return tc;
        }

        private static OpenXmlCompositeElement GetGraphicFrame(Shape refShape)
        {
            GraphicFrame graphicFrame = new GraphicFrame();
            int contentPlaceholderCount = 0;
            UInt32Value graphicFrameId = 1000;
            NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties = new NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties();
            NonVisualDrawingProperties nonVisualDrawingProperties = new NonVisualDrawingProperties()
            {
                Id = ++graphicFrameId,
                Name = "Table" + contentPlaceholderCount.ToString(),
            };

            NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties = new NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties();
            ODrawing.GraphicFrameLocks graphicFrameLocks = new ODrawing.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoGrouping = true };
            nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties.Append(graphicFrameLocks);
            ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties();
            PlaceholderShape placeholderShape = new PlaceholderShape() { Index = graphicFrameId };

            applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties.Append(placeholderShape);
            nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties.Append(nonVisualDrawingProperties);
            nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties.Append(nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties);
            nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties.Append(applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties);

            Transform transform = new Transform()
            {
                Offset = new ODrawing.Offset() { X = refShape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Offset.X, Y = refShape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Offset.Y },
                Extents = new ODrawing.Extents() { Cx = refShape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cx, Cy = refShape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Cy }
            };

            ODrawing.Graphic graphic = new ODrawing.Graphic();
            ODrawing.GraphicData graphicData = new ODrawing.GraphicData() { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table" };
            graphic.Append(graphicData);
            graphicFrame.Append(nonVisualGraphicFrameProperties);
            graphicFrame.Append(transform);
            graphicFrame.Append(graphic);
            return graphicFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note that the template used is a sample template containing two slides only i.e. one title slide and one more blank side with a wordart having some random text written on it.**

**Also the table is filled with data from 4 textboxes present on the aspx page.**

And here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using ODrawing = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using Drawing = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

namespace DocumentFormat.Extensions1
{
    public static class Extensions1
    {


        internal static Slide InsertSlide(this PresentationPart presentationPart, string layoutName, int absolutePosition)
        {
            int slideInsertedPostion = 0;

            UInt32 slideId = 256U;
            slideId += Convert.ToUInt32(presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList.Count());
            Slide slide = new Slide(new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree()));
            SlidePart sPart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>();
            slide.Save(sPart);

            SlideId newSlideId = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList.AppendChild<SlideId>(new SlideId());
            newSlideId.Id = slideId;
            newSlideId.RelationshipId = presentationPart.GetIdOfPart(sPart);
            slideInsertedPostion = presentationPart.SlideParts.Count();
            presentationPart.Presentation.Save();

            var returnVal = ReorderSlides(presentationPart, slideInsertedPostion - 1, absolutePosition - 1);
            return GetSlideByRelationshipId(presentationPart, newSlideId.RelationshipId);
        }
        public static Slide InsertSlide1(this PresentationPart presentationPart, string layoutName, int absolutePosition)
        {
            int slideInsertedPostion = 0;

            UInt32 slideId = 256U;
            slideId += Convert.ToUInt32(presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList.Count());
            Slide slide = new Slide(new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree()));
            SlidePart sPart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>();
            slide.Save(sPart);
            SlideMasterPart smPart = presentationPart.SlideMasterParts.First();
            SlideLayoutPart slPart = smPart.SlideLayoutParts.SingleOrDefault(sl => sl.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Name.Value.Equals(layoutName));
            //SlideLayoutPart slPart = smPart.SlideLayoutParts.SingleOrDefault(sl => sl.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Name.Value.Equals(layoutName));
            sPart.AddPart<SlideLayoutPart>(slPart);
            sPart.Slide.CommonSlideData = (CommonSlideData)smPart.SlideLayoutParts.SingleOrDefault(sl => sl.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Name.Value.Equals(layoutName)).SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Clone();
            SlideId newSlideId = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList.AppendChild<SlideId>(new SlideId());
            newSlideId.Id = slideId;
            newSlideId.RelationshipId = presentationPart.GetIdOfPart(sPart);
            slideInsertedPostion = presentationPart.SlideParts.Count();
            presentationPart.Presentation.Save();

            var returnVal = ReorderSlides(presentationPart, slideInsertedPostion - 1, absolutePosition - 1);
            return GetSlideByRelationshipId(presentationPart, newSlideId.RelationshipId);

        }
        internal static int ReorderSlides(PresentationPart presentationPart, int currentSlidePosition, int newPosition)
        {
            int returnValue = -1;

            if (newPosition == currentSlidePosition) { return returnValue; }
            int slideCount = presentationPart.SlideParts.Count();
            if (slideCount == 0) { return returnValue; }
            int maxPosition = slideCount - 1;
            CalculatePositions(ref currentSlidePosition, ref newPosition, maxPosition);
            if (newPosition != currentSlidePosition)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Presentation presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;
                SlideIdList slideIdList = presentation.SlideIdList;
                SlideId sourceSlide = (SlideId)(slideIdList.ChildElements[currentSlidePosition]);
                SlideId targetSlide = (SlideId)(slideIdList.ChildElements[newPosition]);
                sourceSlide.Remove();
                if (newPosition > currentSlidePosition)
                {
                    slideIdList.InsertAfter(sourceSlide, targetSlide);
                }
                else
                {
                    slideIdList.InsertBefore(sourceSlide, targetSlide);
                }
                returnValue = newPosition;
            }
            presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
            return returnValue;
        }

        private static void CalculatePositions(ref int originalPosition, ref int newPosition, int maxPosition)
        {
            if (originalPosition < 0)
            {
                originalPosition = maxPosition;
            }
            if (newPosition < 0)
            {
                newPosition = maxPosition;
            }
            if (originalPosition > maxPosition)
            {
                originalPosition = maxPosition;
            }
            if (newPosition > maxPosition)
            {
                newPosition = maxPosition;
            }
        }
        private static Slide GetSlideByRelationshipId(PresentationPart presentationPart, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.StringValue relId)
        {
            SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.GetPartById(relId) as SlidePart;
            if (slidePart != null)
            {
                return slidePart.Slide;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        internal static Picture AddPicture(this Slide slide, Shape referingShape, string imageFile)
        {
            Picture picture = new Picture();

            string embedId = string.Empty;
            UInt32Value picId = 10001U;
            string name = string.Empty;

            if (slide.Elements<Picture>().Count() > 0)
            {
                picId = ++slide.Elements<Picture>().ToList().Last().NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Id;
            }
            name = "image" + picId.ToString();
            embedId = "rId" + (slide.Elements<Picture>().Count() + 915).ToString(); // some value

            NonVisualPictureProperties nonVisualPictureProperties = new NonVisualPictureProperties()
            {
                NonVisualDrawingProperties = new NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Name = name, Id = picId, Title = name },
                NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties = new NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties() { PictureLocks = new Drawing.PictureLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true } },
                ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties() { UserDrawn = true }
            };

            BlipFill blipFill = new BlipFill() { Blip = new Drawing.Blip() { Embed = embedId } };
            Drawing.Stretch stretch = new Drawing.Stretch() { FillRectangle = new Drawing.FillRectangle() };
            blipFill.Append(stretch);

            ShapeProperties shapeProperties = new ShapeProperties()
            {
                Transform2D = new Drawing.Transform2D()
                {
                    Offset = new Drawing.Offset() { X = 1554691, Y = 1600200 },
                    Extents = new Drawing.Extents() { Cx = 6034617, Cy = 4525963 }
                }
            };
            Drawing.PresetGeometry presetGeometry = new Drawing.PresetGeometry() { Preset = Drawing.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle };
            Drawing.AdjustValueList adjustValueList = new Drawing.AdjustValueList();

            presetGeometry.Append(adjustValueList);
            shapeProperties.Append(presetGeometry);
            picture.Append(nonVisualPictureProperties);
            picture.Append(blipFill);
            picture.Append(shapeProperties);

            slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Append(picture);

            // Add Image part
            slide.AddImagePart(embedId, imageFile);

            slide.Save();
            return picture;
        }
        private static void AddImagePart(this Slide slide, string relationshipId, string imageFile)
        {
            ImagePart imgPart = slide.SlidePart.AddImagePart(GetImagePartType(imageFile), relationshipId);
            using (FileStream imgStream = File.Open(imageFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                imgPart.FeedData(imgStream);
            }
        }
        private static ImagePartType GetImagePartType(string imageFile)
        {
            string[] imgFileSplit = imageFile.Split('.');
            string imgExtension = imgFileSplit.ElementAt(imgFileSplit.Count() - 1).ToString().ToLower();
            if (imgExtension.Equals("jpg"))
                imgExtension = "jpeg";
            return (ImagePartType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ImagePartType), imgExtension, true);
        }
        public static void Copy(this Stream source, Stream target)
        {
            if (source != null)
            {
                MemoryStream mstream = source as MemoryStream;
                if (mstream != null) mstream.WriteTo(target);
                else
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int length = buffer.Length, size;
                    while ((size = source.Read(buffer, 0, length)) != 0)
                        target.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now here are my queries:
1.In the aspx page if i try to replace the templateFile with my own template(same as the sample)it gives me an error **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"** at this line **Where(sh => sh.NonVisualShapeProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Title.Value == "TableHolder")** under AddTable.Otherwise it works fine.

2.Also in the second slide i am getting the required table but with the word "**image**" written 5 times on top of the page.

3.Also in the powerpoint file generated,the template style is not displayed on the slides except the first and the last slide(i.e the slides which are there in the template).

Thank you.